# How to preserve white space in XSLT variable pass to a href?

Tags: xslt

I have xslt variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="sRemarks">
<xsl:value-of select="remarks"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

I want to pass and view the variable sRemarks in anchor href code but the value have a white space and an enter space.

sample output;

```
Hello!

Hi!
```

Comment: Do you mean the variable contains white space and you want to strip the white space out when passing it to the HREF?

Comment: yes sir and preserve the white space. I will print it to textarea :0

Comment: Please show the XML input and the desired HTML output - as HTML, not as you want the HTMl rendered in the browser. I suspect this may be a case where the whitespace is not being lost during the transformation to HTML, but rather during the rendering of HTML in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're getting the spaces because there are spaces within the variable. Make it a single line...</strike>

```
<xsl:variable name="sRemarks"><xsl:value-of select="remarks"/></xsl:variable>
```

Or select it

```
<xsl:variable name="sRemarks" select="remarks" />
```

**UPDATE**

If you're actually wanting the white-space / carriage returns to remain within the HREF, you will need to "urlencode" the link.

Taken from [here](http://www.jonmiles.co.uk/2009/02/url-encoding-with-xslt/), if you're using XSLT 2 the "fn:encode-for-uri" should work.

**2nd UPDATE**

As pointed out by Michael, the first part of my answer is incorrect, the spacing within the variable should not be picked up (unless you have `xml:space="preserve"`).

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. The whitespace text nodes within the xsl:variable element will not form part of the value of the variable unless there happens to be an xml:space="preserve" attribute in scope somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelKay - good shout. Although I still believe that urlencoding part of my answer is valid